# How to rename an IndexedDB database?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I created an IndexedDB databse named "A" by indexedDB.open method.

Now I want to modify the database name to "B", how can I do it?

I dont't want to create a new database with new name and copy all data from old database to new database.

Comment: why you need to change a database name? generally database name should not tied to data.

Comment: Because I think the old name is ugly :) and maybe conflict with other apps in one site.

Answer (score 5):

From the main [Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) :

> Every database has a name which identifies it within a specific origin.The name can be any string value, including the empty string, and **stays constant** for the lifetime of the database.

So, as it says, the name remains same for entire life.

Comment: Renaming is supported in indexedDb v2.0. See https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/10/whats-new-in-indexeddb-2-0/

Comment: Indexed Database API 2.0 still says the database name "[stays constant for the lifetime of the database](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-IndexedDB-2-20180130/#database-construct)".

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a pain, but you could create a new database with the name you want, and copy everything from the old to the new. If you're using autoincrement IDs and you have cross-references by ID, you might need to generate maps of old-to-new id during transfers, and translate the references.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming is supported in indexedDb v2.0. See https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/10/whats-new-in-indexeddb-2-0/

Comment: This seems to discuss renaming individual *object stores* (roughly, tables) within a particular IndexedDB—not renaming the database itself. (The original question is about changing the name of the database as passed to indexedDB.open.)